# Gitlab 8.12.7 container_registry push error 404

Tags: docker, gitlab

When i try to push my docker image to my "gitlab container registry".I have an 404 error.

When i execute the command : tail -f /var/log/gitlab/registry/current
to see logs i have this message :
err.message="repository name not known to registry".

I can login put can't push.
My external registry url is the same as my "gitlab uri" i have just added the port 4567 to the end.

Thanks for your help